# ClassCastException, Why is my save button not saving checked checkboxes to my db when clicked?

Tags: java, android, classcastexception

I have an `EditContact` class. When opened, it shows me which checkboxes are checked or unchecked. This is done with some code in my `adapter`, which works correctly:

```
    //This is for EditContact, to display checked checkboxes. Numbers not in the array will remain unchecked.
    //for every phone number in the checkedContactsAsArrayList array list...
    for (int number2 = 0; number2 < checkedContactsAsArrayList.size(); number2++) {
        Log.i("MyMessage","checkedContactsAsArrayList is: " + checkedContactsAsArrayList);

        //if a phone number is in our array of checked contacts
        if (checkedContactsAsArrayList.contains(selectPhoneContact.getPhone())) {
            //check the box
            ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setChecked(true);
        }
    }
```

In my `EditContact` class, the user can check or uncheck boxes from a list of contacts. These should be saved if they are checked, and the code in the `adapter` should reflect the new `checkedContactsAsArrayList`, but no matter what is checked, it is always being saved as empty.

In `System.out` I can see `we're in the try part` and then it goes straight to `EditContact: there's a problem here unfortunately`. Can you tell me what is wrong and how to fix it?

Here is the code for my `save` button:

```
  //for the SAVE button
    private void saveContactButton() {

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                System.out.println("you clicked it, save");

                //close the class
                //(we'll be opening it again, will close now so it will be refreshed)
                PopulistoListView.fa.finish();

                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditContact.this);
                // Showing progress dialog for the review being saved
                pDialog.setMessage("Saving...");
                pDialog.show();

                try {
                    System.out.println("we're in the try part");

                    //the user will be able to check contacts who to share the review
                    // with, from their matching contacts list
                    int count = PopulistoContactsAdapter.MatchingContactsAsArrayList.size();

                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        LinearLayout itemLayout = (LinearLayout)recyclerView.getChildAt(i);
                        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)itemLayout.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxContact);
                        SelectPhoneContact contact = (SelectPhoneContact) checkbox.getTag();

                            // make each checked contact in selectPhoneContacts
                            // into an individual
                            // JSON object called checkedContact
                            JSONObject checkedContact = new JSONObject();

                            //if that checkbox is checked, then get the phone number
                        if(checkbox.isChecked()) {

                            // checkedContact will be of the form {"checkedContact":"+353123456"}
                            checkedContact.put("checkedContact", contact.getPhone());

                            // Add checkedContact JSON Object to checkedContacts jsonArray
                            //The JSON Array will be of the form
                            // [{"checkedContact":"+3531234567"},{"checkedContact":"+353868132813"}]
                            //we will be posting this JSON Array to Php, further down below
                            checkedContacts.put(checkedContact);
                            System.out.println("EditContact: checkedcontact JSONObject :" + checkedContact);
                       }

                    }

                    System.out.println("checkedContacts JSON Array " + checkedContacts);


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("EditContact: there's a problem here unfortunately");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //post the review_id in the current activity to EditContact.php and from that
                //get associated values - category, name, phone etc...
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, EditContact_URL,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {

                                Toast.makeText(EditContact.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Toast.makeText(EditContact.this, "there's a problem saving this page", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }

                        }) {

                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        //post the phone number to php to get the user_id in the user table
                        params.put("phonenumberofuser", phoneNoofUserCheck);
                        params.put("review_id", review_id);
                        //the second value, categoryname.getText().toString() etc...
                        // is the value we get from Android.
                        //the key is "category", "name" etc.
                        // When we see these in our php,  $_POST["category"],
                        //put in the value from Android
                        params.put("category", categoryname.getText().toString());
                        params.put("name", namename.getText().toString());
                        params.put("phone", phonename.getText().toString());
                        params.put("address", addressname.getText().toString());
                        params.put("comment", commentname.getText().toString());
                        params.put("public_or_private", String.valueOf(pub_or_priv));

                        //this is the JSON Array of checked contacts
                        //it will be of the form
                        //[{"checkedContact":"+3531234567"},{"checkedContact":"+353868132813"}]
                        params.put("checkedContacts", checkedContacts.toString());

                        return params;

                    }


                };


                AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

                //when saved, go to the PopulistoListView class and update with
                //the edited values
                Intent j = new Intent(EditContact.this, PopulistoListView.class);

                EditContact.this.startActivity(j);

                finish();
                //hide the dialogue box when page is saved
                hidePDialog();
            }


        });
    }
```

Underneath `there's a problem here unfortunately` in `logcat` it says:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to com.example.chris.tutorialspoint.SelectPhoneContact` at `line 318`, which is

```
SelectPhoneContact contact = (SelectPhoneContact) checkbox.getTag();
```

but not sure how to fix it.

In `onBindViewHolder` of my `adapter`:

```
//if the activity is EditContact
        if (whichactivity == 2) {
            //if the row is a matching contact
            if (viewHolder.getItemViewType() == 1)

            {
                //in the title textbox in the row, put the corresponding name etc...
                ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).title.setText(selectPhoneContact.getName());
                ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).phone.setText(selectPhoneContact.getPhone());
                ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setChecked(theContactsList.get(position).getSelected());
                ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setTag(position);
//disable the check box, can't be changed
                //((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setEnabled(false);

                ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        //pos is the row number that the clicked checkbox exists in
                        Integer pos = (Integer) ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.getTag();

                        //NEED THIS TO PRESERVE CHECKBOX STATE
                        if (theContactsList.get(pos).getSelected()) {
                            theContactsList.get(pos).setSelected(false);
                            Toast.makeText(context_type, theContactsList.get(pos).getPhone() + " unclicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } else {

                            theContactsList.get(pos).setSelected(true);
                            Toast.makeText(context_type, theContactsList.get(pos).getPhone() + " clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                        //we want to keep track of checked boxes, so when it is '0'
                        //'Phone Contacts' button will switch to 'Just Me'
                        int count;
                        count = 0;
                        int size = theContactsList.size();
                        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                            if (theContactsList.get(i).isSelected) {
                                count++;
                                // System.out.println("The count is " + count);

                            }
                        }
                        Log.i("MyMessage", "The count is " + count);

                    }


                });



            } else {

                ((nonMatchingContact) viewHolder).title.setText(selectPhoneContact.getName());
                ((nonMatchingContact) viewHolder).phone.setText(selectPhoneContact.getPhone());

            }


            //This is for EditContact, to display the contact the review is shared with
            //for every phone number in the checkedContactsAsArrayList array list...
            for (int number2 = 0; number2 < checkedContactsAsArrayList.size(); number2++) {
                Log.i("MyMessage","checkedContactsAsArrayList is: " + checkedContactsAsArrayList);

                //if a phone number is in our array of checked contacts
                if (checkedContactsAsArrayList.contains(selectPhoneContact.getPhone())) {
                    //check the box
                    ((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setChecked(true);
                }
            }

        }
```

And my `SelectPhoneContact` class:

```
public class SelectPhoneContact {

    String phone;

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    boolean isMatching;

    public boolean isMatching(){return isMatching;}

    public void setIsMatchingContact(boolean isMatching){

        this.isMatching = isMatching;

    }



    //*****************************************
    //this is for the checkbox
    //by default, make it unchecked
    boolean isSelected = false;

    public boolean getSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected){

            isSelected = selected;

    }


    String type_row;

    public String getType_row() {
        return type_row;
    }

    public void setType_row(String type_row) {
        this.type_row = type_row;
    }



}
```

Comment: Can you show how you are setting the tag (`setTag()`) and the code for the class `SelectPhoneContact`?

Comment: Sure, updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are setting an integer as a tag:

```
((MatchingContact) viewHolder).check.setTag(position);
```

And then casting it to an object of the type SelectPhoneContact when you are getting it:

```
SelectPhoneContact contact = (SelectPhoneContact) checkbox.getTag();
```

Perhaps you can try something like:

```
Object position = checkbox.getTag();
if (position instanceof Integer) {
    SelectPhoneContact contact = checkedContactsAsArrayList.get((Integer)position);
}
```

Comment: I've been tryin different things to fix this...but basically with `Integer position = checkbox.getTag();  if (position != null) {SelectPhoneContact contact = checkedContactsAsArrayList.get(position);` I get `Incompatible types.
Required:java.lang.Integer
Found:java.lang.Object` on `Integer position = checkbox.getTag();` and `Incompatible types.
Required:com.example.chris.tutorialspoint.SelectPhoneContact
Found:java.lang.String` on `SelectPhoneContact contact = checkedContactsAsArrayList.get(position); }`

Comment: I added a validation that checks the item is an Integer - it may help.